# Optimal way of running hundreds of thousands of DDL/DML statements MySQL

Tags: mysql, java, amazon-rds

I have about 500k DDL/DML statements that need to be run against a MySQL 5.7 INNODB RDS instance from scratch. A significant portion of these are created table statements.

I'm currently employing a microservice built on Java and using Flyway to run these statements (the service lives in ECS and connects directly to the RDS). This takes about 35 minutes to run all the statements (according to flyway docs, each statement makes a single round trip network request) and these statements have to be repeated as well to further create more schemas/tables (it's essentially tenants/environments).

I am trying to optimize this to reduce this time by as much as I can and wanted some advice on how best to handle it? Should we just be using mysqldump and restore? Should I create my own custom MySQL runner and try to batch the requests?

Comment: What is the initial request of the question, if you have Programming question then Serverfault is the wrong page due Stackoverflow is the right place

Comment: can you tell me the current config of RDS you have ? Also, have you tried performing load testing via sysbench or some other tools ?